# Facebook Javascript SDK new access token in the background

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I refresh a long lived facebook access token in the background? From the facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension)

> Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point,
>   you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to
>   the login flow used by your web app - note that the person will not
>   actually need to login again, they have already authorized your app,
>   so they will immediately redirect back to your app from the login flow
>   with a refreshed token - how this appears to the person will vary
>   based on the type of login flow that you are using, for example if you
>   are using the JavaScript SDK, this will take place in the background,
>   if you are using a server-side flow, the browser will quickly redirect
>   to the Login Dialog and then automatically and immediately back to
>   your app again.

What I'm trying to reconcile is that in order to get a new access token you need to have the user login. In order to login, you must call `FB.login()`. According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#logindialog), a user should click a button in order to login.

> As noted in the reference docs for this function, it results in a
>   pop-up window showing the Login dialog, and therefore should only be
>   invoked as a result of someone clicking an HTML button (so that the
>   pop-up isn't blocked by browsers).

How can you refresh a long lived access token in the background with the facebook javascript SDK?

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: @WizKid I'd love a little more clarity. The user would be required to "re-connect facebook" in order to retrieve an access token for the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only refresh a User Token if the user visits your website: Use [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus) for that. You do not need to use `FB.login` - it would only work on user interaction (click event) anyway, because browsers usually block the popup if you try to call it automatically.

Comment: Is this still true with the current SDK and the response.authResponse.accessToken has the same expiration date of the current one. I am running the command in the browser console, could it be a problem (as you say it woud work on user interaction).

Comment: this should still be true, it will refresh automatically when it is not valid anymore. if it is not expired yet, there is no need to refresh.